# JAXWS caching in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jax-ws

We have an application server that exposes a host of webservices. We are running a tomcat on the side that uses those webservices in JSF applications to provide a user interface. Suppose we have a bean that has a method "getWebservice()" that returns the proxy class used by jaxws to communicate with the webservice. This allows us to interact with the webservice with minimal effort: generate using wsimport, then use #{myBean.webservice.myProperty} etc

However as you can see this would require a *lot* of webservice interaction when reusing exposed methods. In our usecase most methods are rather static, at least for the duration of a @RequestScoped bean so the interaction of most methods should be cached once it is called (at least for one request).

Currently our setup is to create wrapper services in the bean and each wrapper does exactly the same thing:

```
if (methodResponse == null)
     methodResponse = getWebservice().getMethod();
return methodResponse;
```

You can see that this gets very tiresome very quickly. Is there a way to annotate a jaxws method for caching? Or can I generate my own proxy class based on the interface and somehow "chain" it to the proxy used by jaxws (and perform generic caching) or can I create my own annotation that performs the caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another caching [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) around your *web service client* proxy object, and provide it with an [`InvocationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html), that caches the result of method invocations.

Check out [this blog post](http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/caching-with-dynamic-proxy-classes) to see the complete *step-by-step* instruction and download sample code.

Comment: I have not yet had time to actually create a proxy as per the tutorial but I've scanned over the article and it seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!